# Frequency of digits in powers of $2, 3, 5$ and $7$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

For a fixed integer $N\in\mathbb{N}$ consider the multi-set $A_2(N)$ of decimal digits of $2^n$, for $n=1,2,\dots,N$. For example,
$$A_2(8)=\{2,4,8,1,6,3,2,6,4,1,2,8,2,5,6\}.$$
Similarly, define the multi-sets $A_3(N), A_5(N)$ and $A_7(N)$.

I can't be sure if I have seen any discussion of the below question. If you do, please do let me know of a reference.

> **QUESTION.** For $N$ large, is it true that the most frequent digit in $A_x(N)$ is $x$, where $x\in\{2,3,5,7\}$?

Comment: Why do you believe that?  For large $N$ I would have thought that all the digits would appear roughly equally often (and I don't think we can prove such things).

Comment: I suspect so due to numerical data, but could not be sure. Hence, I asked.

Comment: How big is the numerical data?  The initial digits and final digits will have biases (e.g. Benford's law, last digit must be even for powers of 2 etc), but eventually I'd guess that the decimal digits just look random.

Comment: @Lucia The Benford's law bias is of size $\log N/N$, I think. Since random error in a list of length $N^2$ is of size $N$ on average, it's possible that these biases will win 100% of the time, and even maybe for all sufficiently large $N$? On the other hand the low-digits bias may have size just $1/N$.

Comment: @WillSawin:  That's interesting!  If the Benford bias somehow wins out, then I guess 1 should be the most frequent -- but the data so far is probably not conclusive.

Comment: @Lucia Unfortunately what I wrote now seems wrong. The Benford bias in the $i$th digit from leading declines like $10^{-i}$, so the total bias is constant times $1/N$ and is of the same order as the random bias (and the last digit bias). So maybe what we should expect is that for different values of $N$ we will see different most frequent digits, but that distribution is not uniform (like Chebyshev's bias).

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer but some numercal data for $A_2(N)$. Here digits are ordered according to their frecuences ($2$, $4$ and $6$ look like most frequent):
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
N=1000: & 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 3, 0, 7\\
N=2000: & 2, 1, 6, 4, 8, 5, 3, 9, 7, 0 \\
N=3000: & 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 8, 0, 5, 7, 9 \\
N=5000: & 2, 0, 4, 1, 8, 6, 5, 3, 7, 9 \\
N=6000: & 4, 8, 2, 1, 9, 7, 0, 6, 5, 3 \\
N=7000: & 4, 9, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 0 \\
N=8000: & 4, 8, 7, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 5, 0 \\
N=10000: & 4, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 6, 3, 5, 0 \\
N=15000: & 4, 2, 8, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0, 5, 9 \\
N=20000: & 6, 4, 3, 8, 2, 1, 7, 9, 0, 5 \\
N=25000: & 6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 9, 7, 5, 0 \\
N=30000: & 6, 9, 4, 3, 2, 8, 1, 0, 7, 5 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I presume the frequencies are compatible with the "asymptotic iid" conjecture - aren't they?

Comment: @R W yes, but I didn't try to study deviation from iid.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: Thanks for the data and stat. I keep getting $2$ as the most frequent number for $A_2(1000)$. Can you please check?

Comment: Yes, $2$ is the most frequent there. For $A_2(1000)$ I get the following digit counts:
$$ \matrix{0 &14899\cr
1 &15257\cr
2 &15423\cr
3 &14984\cr
4 &15239\cr
5 &15019\cr
6 &15217\cr
7 &14893\cr
8 &15181\cr
9 &15054\cr
}$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I totally agree!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you! The error is fixed up. I took first string from the wrong place. For $N=2000$ I've got $(59711, 0), (60679, 1), (61067, 2), (60146, 3), (60586, 4), (60198, 
  5), (60655, 6), (59831, 7), (60470, 8), (60019, 9).$

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: Is the rest correct, for $N=3000$ and up?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Yes, I've check it one more time. n = 10000; LLL = Flatten[IntegerDigits[Table[2^i, {i, 1, n}]]];
MMM = {}; For[i := 0, i <= 9, i++, 
 MMM = Append[MMM, {Count[LLL, i], i}]]
Transpose[Sort[MMM, #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &]][[2]]

Comment: Could you please report the exact counts for some large $N$? It may be helpful to know the size of the bias.